# Skype Optimization - Port Forwarding on a Router

Tags: networking, skype, port-forwarding, performance

I was watching this [Video](http://www.butterscotch.com/show/Super-Charge-Skype) which talked about using port-forwarding to optimize your LAN for skype calls.  According to the video, as explained in the first couple of minutes in the video, the reason you would need optimization is because if the person your call has a firewall setup, your connection has to go-through a third-party computer to connect to them.  I believe I stated this correct (maybe not).

None the less, my question is this: **do both parties on the call need to enable port forwarding to optimize skype, or just one party (person)**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking only the person that is RECEIVING a connection should need a port forward. But it's really best if you port forward on both ends.

A good place to start is the portforward.com guides for Skype. You can get to them here:
[portforward.com](http://portforward.com/english/applications/port_forwarding/Skype/Skypeindex.htm)

They should have a writeup specifically for your router and Skype. If not, just let them know and they'll add it.

BTW, UPNP is an option as well, but lots of computers have it disabled and lots of routers do not support it. If you want to be certain then forward the ports.

Comment: Skype is two way communication, which means traffic is flowing in both directions, so port forwarding would be needed on both ends if it were necessary to forward ports for skype to function.

Answer (score 1):

uPnP is automatic port-forwarding, Skype uses it and it's almost certain both your routers do. Try to get that working first. If you can connect to each other, but it's poor quality I don't think that's anything to do with ports, forwarding or firewalls.